# Load state of particular recyclerview item

Tags: java, android

so I have recyclerview populated with data from database. Each row contains two buttons one for play and second for stop time. So what I'm trying is to save state of buttons inside recyclerview. And I used

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().
                                putInt(Constants.numberOfbutton, getAdapterPosition()).apply();
```

to save particular position. I have inserted that line of code inside button click and I checked it's saving correct position. What I'm trying to achieve is, when user enters the app after closing if he lefts any of the buttons in play mode to restore that state and continue timer. But problem is when user enters the app all buttons are running. I'm using chronometer for presentation of the time. I think here is the problem in this method:

```
 private void startTime(int position ) {
        Data data = datas.get(position);
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Long.parseLong(data.getTime()));
        chronometer.start();

    }
```

UPDATE EXPLANATION:

So I can load from database for each item of recyclerview it's time, date, name etc. But I can't figure it out how to play chronometer of just particular item when user enters the app again. NOTE AGAIN: I'm performing correct saving `getAdapterAtPosition` and loading data from `PreferenceManager`. I've checked that. Even I tried putting the number of one of rows but same issue appears.
Any help very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of `chronometer`?

Comment: @azizbekian  I'm using it as a timer. So I'm saving time in database after user exit the app and after open up it again I count the difference and adding to the time and that works. But problem is the saving button state and chronometer state. After user enter the app if he leaves at least one button playing instead founding that just that button is playing unfortunetly all buttons are playing and all chronometers are counting the time.

Comment: `unfortunetly all buttons are playing` how that happens? If you correctly save the state in database, that shouldn't happen, right?

Comment: @azizbekian I have checked saving `getAdapterPosition()` by putting breakpoints and saving is correct. So I don't know why but after user enter again the app he should be find that button and chronometer playing which he actually leaves playing after exiting the app. But somehow all chornometers are playing the time. So probably I'm making mistake in loading state.

Comment: @Yupi Could you please share your code of adapter class and class the where you start storing data.

Comment: If you have your data in a database why don't you persist the database id with the time info. When you come back, you just need to check when the record is loaded into the recycler view and update the buttons accordingly. This would be in onBindViewHolder() of the Adapter class.

Comment: your question itself needs to be explained, put some code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. I save the boolean in database actually I used 1 or 0 than parse that to true or false acordingly is button play pressed or not. Thank you all for your comments and trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use handler or alarm service instead of chronometer